# HTML5 newbie Q | nav > ul VS nav ul / What's the difference?

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering, in CSS3, when we type for exemple :

```
nav > ul{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

It means that the ul's margin INSIDE the nav element will be 0px. Good.

BUT! What does mean ? What's the difference with nav > ul ?! :

```
nav ul{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Also, little question to finish : What is the purpose of nav ? We can make a navigation menu without it.

Thanks,

Tech.

Comment: > means direct child: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) should be your go to resource for CSS selectors. With regards to w3Schools, be aware they are **not** associated with W3C.

Comment: To answer you sub question, you don't  **need** to use it but in most cases it is *best practice* to use it : http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Answer (score 1):

ul is a child of nav for a case "nav > ul" whereas ul is descendant of nav for a case "nav ul".

For example:

```
<div class="first">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="second">
          <p></p>
    </div> 
</div>

.first p {
    /*** This will target all the <p> elements in the HTML above ***/
}

.first > p {
    /*** This will target all <p> elements except the one nested within the "second" class ***/
}
```

source: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/difference-between-descendant-and-child-selectors